# PHP Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, mysql

I want update multiple rows using checkbox. my script works, but showing error messages after ini_set display_errors

Here is code:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $checked = $_POST['checkbox'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE trace SET status='Delivered' WHERE id='$checked[$i]'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

It's showing Notice: Undefined offset row number

What is wrong?

Comment: Undefined offset ???? it's missing part of the message

Comment: Where is `$count` defined?  Also, you are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: you are ckecing $_POST['submit'], but no checking $_POST['checkbox'], also $count isn't defined

Comment: **Don't paraphrase error messages.**  "Notice: Undefined offset." is not the error message it gave you.  The error message was much longer.  It included a line number.  We need the entire message, and you need to tell us which line in your code is that line number.

Comment: did you do a `var_dump($_POST['checkbox'])` to see just how many (if any) entries you received? You're just ASSUMINg that `$count` is the correct size for the received data

Comment: @BekaGurgenidze You need to stop, look at what you code is doing and start again.  The `$count` is the number of results returned from the database, and it is being used to index an apparently unrelated variable.  There are going to be errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error

```
Notice: Undefined offset
```

is in essence saying that you have attempted to reference a value of an array that does not exist.

Reviewing your code, there are two possible instances where this can happen, first `$_POST['checkbox']` and second `$checked[$i]`.

You can resolve this error by something like this

```
if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
   $checked = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : null;
   if (is_array($checked))
   {
     foreach ($checked as $check)
     {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE trace SET status='Delivered' WHERE id='$check'") or die(mysql_error());
     }
   }
}
```

Note the above code should not be used in production as it is not secure.

Note also that `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli for database queries.

Comment: Having reviewed your edited code sample, there are inherent errors that cannot be resolved easily.

Comment: I want update multiple rows with check box. my script works, but showing error messages after ini_set display_errors

Answer (score 0):

if you defined:

```
$count = count($_POST['checkbox']);
```

Then you need to use $count - 1 as you start iteration from zero.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++ ){
    // ....
}
```

Or you should better use foreach instead - no need to deal with counting index.

```
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) 
{
    // you will use $checkbox instead $checked[$i] in this case
}
```